# Google gtl framework integration giving error with Simulator but working with Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate Google gtl framwork with my app. But It give error as below.

```
Ignoring file /Users/mani/Documents/Example/GooglePlusExample/SampleApp/Security.framework/Security, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/mani/Documents/Example/GooglePlusExample/SampleApp/Security.framework/Security (2 slices)

 "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain removePasswordForService:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:


      -[GPPSignIn randomString] in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)


  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch saveParamsToKeychainForName:accessibility:authentication:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecClass", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:


      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:


      -[GPPSignIn randomString] in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)


  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:


      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

But I've follow their instruction correct. Security.framework are added, also `Other Linker Flags: -ObjC` have set correctly. I can assume, there is silly mistake. But I couldn't found out. Please help me.

**Note:** I'm using xcode5.0.

**Update:** I've added all frameworks which they'd mentioned. See my screeshot.
[image]

**Update2:** Now it's working with iPod Touch-5 devices, But not working with simulator. I don't know, How it's working with device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18080078/2522603 ...check here..it is minor mistake...hope it ll help u...

Comment: @Immi Could you tell that minor mistake? That link direct me to youtube video.

Comment: ya please go through the video, i faced lots of error before watching this video i solved all. i m dam sure, u ll too. please check all the steps, you have followed. In case any issue please feel free to pint me. I m there to answer you...

Comment: ok I'll let you know if It will solve my problem. My question is about google plus framework. But you direct me to google-drive integration step. Any way I will try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have unintentionally copied the `Security.framework` to your project instead of just linking to it from the Framework search path.

File path shows the framework path,

```
/SampleApp/Security.framework/Security
```

Check you project directory for `.framework` file and delete it. Clean + Build again. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file) for few more workarounds.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow man. You found it. Issue fixed. I've remove securtiy.framework my project and project directory. And BuildSetting -> Build Phase -> Linked binary with libs -> add security framework. Thank amar :)

Comment: But don't know why it's work with device and why not with simulator?

Comment: @Mani Don't know the exact reason, but `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` setting of your project gets messed.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the SystemConfiguration framework - try adding that and you should be good to go.

Comment: No man. I've added this too. see my updated question with screeshot.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild, and maybe resetting the simulator?

Comment: Ya I've tried that also. Did you see updated question? It's working with device but not with simulator. Did you see this " missing required architecture i386 in file in first line of error"?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly shows that the framework ( Google gtl ) is not built for i386 architecture (simulator).Instead the framework is built for device architectures (armv7 and armv7s). It will not work in simulator.

If you want to run on simulator you supposed to get simulator version of Google gtl framework.

Comment: What you mean by `i386 architecture `? Is anything special architecture for simulator?

Comment: Yes, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874519/ios-simulator-on-mac-is-running-i386-architecture-not-armv7

Comment: Ok. But I couldn't accept with this line `It will not work in simulator`. I do some RnD and let you know.